# Login coded in PHP just refreshes over and over?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Using PHP and MySQL to make a login/registration system. Registration is in and I'd say it works alright. However, I'm having some problems with the [login page](http://ewsprojects.com/~lyons/login.php).

No matter what, it just kind of refreshes the page and I'm not sure what's wrong. Here's the loginaccount.php script I have running on the form:

**

### EDIT:

**

Thanks for the help so far guys! But I'm still running into a pretty annyoing problem. Now, no matter what, it still doesn't log in, even though now I'm actually getting the error message I set up. Updated code below:

```
<?php

//Database Information

$dbhost = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";

//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

session_start();
$username = $_POST[‘username’];
$password = md5($_POST[‘password’]);

$query = "select * from registerusers where username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
$error = "Incorrect login, please try again.";
include "login.php";
echo "<span class=error_message>".$error."</span>"; 

} else {
$_SESSION['username'] = "$username";
include "login.php";
echo "<span class=success_message>Welcome! You are now logged in.</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your mysql_query() call has a SQL injection security vulnerability. PHP now recommends using MySQLi or PDO extensions, together with prepared statements+parameter binding to avoid this. If use of the mysql_ family of functions is necessary, you should use the mysql_real_escape_string function on all variables before interpolating them into a string.

Comment: Also, it looks like what is happening is that the `include "login.php"` statement is being triggered, but you aren't doing anything with the $error variable and so it doesn't get output on that page.

Comment: Ok, that actually made a lot of sense (I'm a beginner when it comes to PHP and MySQL as this is mainly an introductory project for me). I'll work on the security of everything later, I just want to get every thing semi-running to begin with. I figured it out, but now I'm having a bigger problem: every login results in the error message I set up. Is this because I'm using md5 for passwords?

Comment: Re: "Is this because I'm using md5 for passwords?" It's hard to say without seeing what's in your database. Try changing the login to not have the `password =` statement and see if that allows you to login as any user. P.S. just so you know, md5 for passwords is also insecure. You should use PHP's built-in crypt() function to encode the passwords instead, preferably with the blowfish option.

Comment: When I get rid of the "and password='$password'" part of the $query and just have the username part in there, it logs in successfully. However, I can't seem to find out a way to make it take the password as well.

Comment: Try using a tool like phpmyadmin to test your query, and see if you can get it to work there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments on questions yet, but I've got a possible reason for your problem.

Since you're only including (and not redirecting) the users to a page, the login page will just stay where it is and just keep including the files - doing the same things over and over. Try `header('Location: memberspage.php')` instead.